# Can a triatomic linear molecule rotate around two different center of masses?

Tags: rotational-kinematics, rotation, molecular-dynamics

Consider a triatomic linear molecule with unequal masses $m_A \neq m_B \neq m_C$ where $m_B$ is in the middle. If the molecule would rotate, the axis of rotation (center of mass) would therefore be somewhere distant from the middle, its distance to each of these masses would be $S_A, S_B$ and $S_C$ respectively.
If the center of mass is between $m_B$ and $m_C$, then the following formule holds
$$m_A \cdot S_A + m_B \cdot S_B= m_C\cdot S_C$$
If the center of mass is between $m_A$ and $m_B$, then the following formula holds
$$m_A\cdot S_A = m_B \cdot S_B + m_C \cdot S_C$$
I have deduced these equations from a formula from [this scenario](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/6-consider-linear-triatomic-molecule-abc-masses-mi-m2-m-bond-lengths-r-r2-atom-c-let-point-q26860775)

Both of these equations appear to have solutions for the *same masses* while each $S$ stays within the length of the molecule.

Does this mean that the molecule can rotate around two different center of masses? If yes, how can one determine beforehand around which center of mass it will rotate?

Comment: You are using three variables ($S_A$, $S_B$ and $S_C$) to examine the problem. They are not independent from each other. I would suggest having two constants $d_{AB}$ and $d_{BC}$ for the distance between the atoms and a single variable $x$ for the distance of the centre of mass from one of the atoms.

Comment: You will find that there is only one solution, and you have implicitly assigned the signs of your Ss where you should not have.